# Int is always 0 - JSF

Tags: jsf, jsf-2

I have a problem with my JSF application as I am creating User object with int value of coupons and I want to show them, but it doesn't work. Coupons are always 0. The rest (username and stuff) is loaded normally.

Here is some code:
Service.java

```
        User admin = new User("JustCinek", "26454dd458d9b07364a3a198fcfd459f", "marcingadomski94@gmail.com", "Jettesvej 15, 2TV", "8220", "Aarhus", 100);
        users.add(admin);
```

User.java

```
public User(String username, String password, String email, String address, String zipCode, String town, int coupons){
    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;
    this.email = email;
    this.address = address;
    this.zipCode = zipCode;
    this.town = town;
    this.coupons = coupons;
}

public int getCoupons(){ return this.coupons; }
public void setCoupons(int coupons){ this.coupons = coupons; }
```

index.xhtml

```
            <h:form rendered="#{user.loggedIn}">
                <div id="menuItem" class="clearfix">
                    Witaj, #{user.username}!<br></br>
                    Twoje kupony: #{user.coupons}
                </div>
            </h:form>
```

Username shows normally, coupons are always 0 even if User object is created in Service class with coupons value set to 100

Comment: I see no reason why it shouldn't work. Maybe you get different object in the page. Try to change int to Integer. Then you will see if it's not initialized at all or set to 0 somewhere.

Comment: Changing int to Integer didn't help at all

Comment: is it still 0? is it NULL? Did you also change the setters?

Comment: I have the same object. It seems like it is not initialized as it should be, because Integer is returning null. I have changed everything.

Comment: What you've posted here does not provide a clear picture of your setup: at what point is `setCoupons` called? What's the scope of your backing bean? What app server/container are you running?

Comment: Which server are you running ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are just mixing your `User` instantiation here :

```
User admin = new User("JustCinek", "26454dd458d9b07364a3a198fcfd459f", "marcingadomski94@gmail.com", "Jettesvej 15, 2TV", "8220", "Aarhus", 100);
```

Which is happening in a different bean (`service.java`) with the `user` manged bean instantiation which will happen when you first call your bean.

Notice that the `user` Object that you are using inside your JSF page and  which is the name of your managed bean `User` is different then `admin` which you intantiate in your service bean, so probably the username you are getting after rendering your page is some username that you are setting or initializing inside the managed bean and not in your service bean, which explain why you can see a valid username while your coupons remains `0` (wasn't initialized so it will get it's default value, which is `0` for a `int`)

Comment: That was a problem. Thank You for helping.